# Let z, w be complex numbers with |z|=|w|=1 and z$\overline{w}$=$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}i$ find out $|z-w|^{2}$

Tags: complex-numbers

This may seem like a really easy question to you guys, but I'm getting confused.

So I know that z and w lie on the unit circle cause they have a modulus of 1.

And I've turned z$\overline{w}$ into polar form which gave me 1cis$\frac{\pi}{3}$ so I know that that lies on unit circle too (obviously anyway cause z and w lie on it anyway)

From what I know when multiplying complex numbers I can just add their $\theta$, so I need two that add to $\frac{\pi}{3}$ which is quite a few of numbers.

I tested (1cis$\frac{\pi}{6}$)$^{2}$ which should give me 1cis$\frac{\pi}{3}$, and in standard for this is just ($\frac{\sqrt 3}{2} + \frac{1}{2}i$)$^{2}$ but as I'm working with conjugate I would do

($\frac{\sqrt 3}{2} + \frac{1}{2}i$) - ($\frac{\sqrt 3}{2} - \frac{1}{2}i$) = i which will have a modulus of 1, even when squared.

But then I also tested (1cis$\frac{4\pi}{3}$)($\pi$) again should give me 1cis$\frac{\pi}{3}$, which again as I'm working with conjugate I would do

(-$\frac{1}{2}$-$\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}i$)(-1+0i) = $\frac{1}{2}$-$\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}i$ which will have a modulus of 2 and then squaring it will give me 4.

After testing those two I just got really confused about if the question has just 1 answer. Any insight would help thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For any two complex numbers $z$ and $w$, can $|z-w|^2$ be expressed in terms of just $|z|$, $|w|$, and $z \bar w$ in a straightforward manner? Indeed,
$$|z - w|^2 = (z - w)(\bar z - \bar w) = z \bar z - (w \bar z + z \bar w) + w \bar w$$
Do you see $|z|$ and $|w|$ lurking in this expression? And what is the relation between $z \bar w$ and $w \bar z$?

Comment: $z\overline{w}$ and $w\overline{z}$ should just be the same right? I'm not positive about that.

Comment: @JohnOkley: No. They're complex conjugates of one another.

Comment: Alright, yeah that was a little dumb of me there. So I would just be subtracting the 2 real parts of that, which I have that makes sense thank you.

Comment: This makes sense, but I'm just wondering why did I get a different answer when I did the second thing I tested?

Answer (score 0):

$|z-w|^2=(z-w)\overline{(z-w)}=|z|^2+|w|^2-2\Re(z\bar{w}=1+1-2.1/2=1.$

Comment: $-2\Re(z\bar{w}) = -2\Re(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i) = -2(\frac{1}{2}) = -1$

Comment: Thanks. It was a typo.